# Developing with Git and SSH access on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, node.js, amazon-beanstalk

We are using EC2 to develop one of our application and we are using Git and SSH to access our EC2 server and deploy files. Unfortunately, AWS breaks some data, changes IP addresses and make other things which make our development awful.

I guess this is because AWS Elastic Beanstalk tends to "optimize" resources, but the question is: may we ever develop our app using classic Git deployment and SSH access? Or we HAVE to use another deployment model with AWS EC2?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk uses Auto Scaling groups to manage the underlying EC2 instances. The EC2 instances are managed behind an Elastic Load Balancer. At any time, an EC2 instance may be terminated and replaced. At any time, the Elastic Load Balancer may change it's IP address.

You should never need to SSH or RDP into the underlying EC2 instances if you are using Elastic Beanstalk.

Elastic Beanstalk is not intended to be deployed using SSH. Plain and simple. If you want to SSH into your EC2 instances to deploy your application, then don't use Elastic Beanstalk.

To properly use Elastic Beanstalk, you should upload your application version as a new "Elastic Beanstalk Version", and allow Elastic Beanstalk to deploy it to the EC2 instances.

There is a way to use git to push your application to Elastic Beanstalk, but there are very specific instructions for that.

You CAN use brute force git and SSH to deploy your application to EC2, but to do that, you should launch and manage the EC2 instance(s) yourself.